# How to avoid subsurf distortions on cylindrical objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I made a cylindrical object which transitions to a squarish block. However there is some distortion at the transition:

[image]

If I add a loopcut to get a nicer surface there, it gives the cylinder a not-very-round edge:

[image]

What are some topological tricks for getting smooth subsurf without interfering with other parts of the model?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Ever since I can remember I've had similar problem. Haven't found the satisfactory solution yet, though :(. Maybe somebody here'll find it.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40788/how-to-avoid-subsurf-distortions-on-cylindrical-objects  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218507/how-to-cut-or-extrude-a-cube-rectangle-from-a-cylinder-curved-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296646/pinching-problem-with-sub-surface-modifier

Answer (score 3):

Although there are several ways to do this, I would recommend selecting the outlining edges:

[image: select]

And then bevel them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>:

[image: bevel]

[image: subdivision]

Comment: Odd.. For me beveling creates a tri at the corner, which causes even worse distortion: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JLOQ6.gif

Comment: I think you may have to bevel the cross edges afterwards.

Comment: @gandalf3 I think the key point is the extra edges where you get the distortion. You have 3 edges following the top of the cylinder where novice has one. Also adding another segment to the bevel can turn a corner tri into a quad.

Comment: @sambler I tried adding more segments, but that just subdivided the tri. I tested it with simpler geometry than in my .blend; see [this gif](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JLOQ6.gif. It appeared to behave the same with and without the surrounding edge loops

Comment: @gandalf3 don't do the one across at the same time, do it afterwards