# Pinching problem with Sub surface modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface, bevel

I tried to make the compensator for an [AK-74](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AK-74), but I encountered the following problem. I don't know how to solve it, bevel doesn't work as it's supposed to because after using bevel some verticals always go up and I get this problem. How to solve this problem?

The problem:
[image: The problem]

Grid without bevel:
[image: Grid without bevel]

Grid with bevel:
[image: Grid with bevel]

Blend file: [image]

Comment: i can't reproduce the problem. the file you shared doesn't have any bevel modifier to it so i tried adding one myself but it seems fine result so I can't reproduce your problem. please attach a file with the problem in it.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Sorry maybe I didn't fully explain the problem. The problem is that when I manually add a bevel to the necessary edges in order for the modifier (Subdivision surface) to work normally, then after adding the subdivision surface itself, clips appear there that make the compensator cylinder a little crooked. Link to the Blend with "Subdivision surface" modifier https://blend-exchange.com/b/mjZV0Wnl

Comment: the problem with your mesh is that it has [this curving non-planar n-gon face](https://snipboard.io/vQaz7o.jpg) which causes the shading problem. you have to add more geometry to it. non-planar faces are a no go especially if they are not quad faces unless it is all flat. i recommend trying to make the faces all quad

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you very much, you have almost solved my problem, I just watched the video how to solve this problem, and did everything as in the video, just for my shape, unfortunately it seems that this problem cannot be completely solved because when using a bevel, some vertices are raised, which causes the clips to reappear, but this the problem was very much minimized, now it is visible, but we need to look closely. Thank you so much, now I have learned a little more and I will better understand how to solve such problems

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40788/how-to-avoid-subsurf-distortions-on-cylindrical-objects  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218507/how-to-cut-or-extrude-a-cube-rectangle-from-a-cylinder-curved-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296646/pinching-problem-with-sub-surface-modifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this topology................

[image]

Comment: can you please send me blend file?

Comment: I realise that there is still a bit of pinching with a 16 vertex cylinder so you probably need to switch to a hight resolution, like 24 or 32

Comment: By the way, I noticed that when I increase the number of edges in the cylinder, there are almost no clips left, I'm just used to working with 16 edges, since for me this is the optimal amount when Shade smooth works well. So I'll have to change the number of edges. Thank you